# Python function not working on Pandas Dataframe when subsetted in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, slice

I have created a number of very simple functions that I want to apply to a pandas DataFrame. For example:

```
def dir_flag(start, end):
   try:
      if start < end:
         return '+'
      else:
         return '-'
   except:
      return 'NA'
```

I have imported a csv file into a DataFrame called "mydata", and can apply my function:

```
mydata['direction'] = mydata.apply(lambda x: dir_flag(x['START_NODE'], x['END_NODE']), axis=1)
```

This works fine. However when I try to apply this function - or similar ones to a Pandas DataFrame created as a subset of "mydata" I get the following Error: `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 0`. FYI `mydata` contain a 3 level multiindex.

The subsetting occurs in the following loop:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice

idx1_levels = mydata.index.unique(level='idx_level1').tolist()

for x in idx1_levels:
   idx1_subset = mydata.loc[idx[x], ['START_NODE','END_NODE']]
   idx2_levels = idx1_subset.index.unique(level='idx_level2').tolist()
   for y in idx2_levels:

       idx2_subset = idx1_subset.loc[idx[y]]

       idx3_subset = idx2_subset.loc[idx[slice(None), 1.0], ['START_NODE','END_NODE']]

       idx3_subset['direction'] = journey_offset.apply(lambda a: dir_flag(a['START_NODE'], a['END_NODE']), axis=1)
```

It is the `idx3_subset = idx2_subset.loc[idx[slice(None), 1.0], ['START_NODE','END_NODE']]` statement that seems to cause the issue, as I can happily apply my function to the `idx2_subset`

Please note I am very new to Python, and I strongly suspect that there is a better way of subsetting my original DataFrame (maybe using a groupby method for example). I am very happy to receive suggestions of how the overall subsetting can be improved - but please can any answer address the specific question of why this is not working, as this will help improve my understanding of how Pandas DataFrames work.

A simplified version of the csv read in is:

```
idx_level1|idx_level2|idx_level3|idx_level4|START_NODE|END_NODE
353386066294006|1142|2018-09-20T07:57:26Z|1|18260004567689|18260005575180
353386066294006|1142|2018-09-20T07:57:26Z|2|18260004567689|18260004240718
353386066294006|1142|2018-09-20T07:57:26Z|3|18260005359901|18260004567689
353386066294006|1142|2018-09-20T07:57:31Z|1|18260004567689|18260005575180
353386066294006|1142|2018-09-20T07:57:31Z|2|18260004567689|18260004240718
353386066294006|1142|2018-09-20T07:57:31Z|3|18260005359901|18260004567689
353386066294006|1142|2018-09-20T07:57:36Z|1|18260004567689|18260005575180
353386066294006|1142|2018-09-20T07:57:36Z|2|18260004567689|18260004240718
353386066294006|1142|2018-09-20T07:57:36Z|3|18260005359901|18260004567689
353386066736543|22|2018-04-17T07:08:23Z|||
353386066736543|22|2018-04-17T07:08:24Z|||
353386066736543|22|2018-04-17T07:08:25Z|||
353386066736543|22|2018-04-17T07:08:26Z|||
353386066736543|403|2018-07-02T16:55:07Z|1|18260004580350|18260005235340
353386066736543|403|2018-07-02T16:55:07Z|2|18260005235340|18260005141535
353386066736543|403|2018-07-02T16:55:07Z|3|18260005235340|18260005945439
353386066736543|403|2018-07-02T16:55:07Z|4|18260006215338|18260005235340
353386066736543|403|2018-07-02T16:55:07Z|5|18260004483352|18260005945439
353386066736543|403|2018-07-02T16:55:07Z|6|18260004283163|18260006215338
353386066736543|403|2018-07-02T16:55:01Z|1|18260004580350|18260005235340
353386066736543|403|2018-07-02T16:55:01Z|2|18260005235340|18260005141535
353386066736543|403|2018-07-02T16:55:01Z|3|18260005235340|18260005945439
353386066736543|403|2018-07-02T16:55:01Z|4|18260006215338|18260005235340
353386066736543|403|2018-07-02T16:55:01Z|5|18260004483352|18260005945439
353386066736543|403|2018-07-02T16:55:01Z|6|18260004283163|18260006215338
```

And the code I use to read in is as follows:

```
mydata = pd.read_csv('/myloc/my_simple_data.txt', sep='|', 
 dtype={'idx_level1': 'int',
        'idx_level2': 'int',
        'idx_level3': 'str',
        'idx_level4': 'float',
        'START_NODE': 'str',
        'END_NODE': 'str'},
 parse_dates = ['idx_level3'],
 index_col=['idx_level1','idx_level2','idx_level3','idx_level4'])
```

Interestingly whilst putting together this dataset - I realized that the error only occurs when I have data that has nulls in it - NB this includes nulls in one level of the index. The index here is legitimately null i.e. this is NOT an error in the data.

Comment: Could you include a sample of your dataframe? Make sure your error is reproducible here and that those trying to help solve your problem have all of the necessary information.

Comment: Hi Rahlf23, I've edited to include an example dataset - this now makes me believe the issue is due to nulls in one level of the index - but given that this can be the case, how can I circumvent the errors?

Comment: Hi! Your sample code doesn't work as `idx` is not defined. However, it seems as if indeed there must a better way to subset your dataframe. Could you perhaps tell me what subset you are trying to select and why? I think we can help you better then

Comment: Also, what is `journey_offset`? Please make sure your data and code is compilable and runnable from our empty Python environments. See [MCVE].

Comment: This screams of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should try to avoid `for` loops entirely with Pandas. If you share (possibly in a new question) what you are trying to achieve with a [mcve], you are more likely to find a good solution.

Comment: Apologies - made a couple of mistakes whilst trying to make my code more generic for this question - have edited and believe I have corrected the issues. I have managed to solve the immeduate issue of this question myself by replacing NaN values in the lowest index level with a value, however, I still want to know why nulls cause an issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem stems from doing a index slice on a multiindex where one of the levels contains nulls. The solution is therefore to replace the null value with a constant:

```
mydata = pd.read_csv('/myloc/my_simple_data.txt', sep='|', 
 dtype={'idx_level1': 'int',
        'idx_level2': 'int',
        'idx_level3': 'str',
        'idx_level4': 'float',
        'START_NODE': 'str',
        'END_NODE': 'str'},
 parse_dates = ['time']);

mydata.idx_level4 = mydata.idx_level4.fillna(1.0)

mydata.set_index(['idx_level1','idx_level2','idx_level3','idx_level4'], inplace=True)
```

Whilst this does answer the question, in terms of understanding what specifically causes the error and give a method for avoiding it - I am still at a loss as to why nulls cause a problem in the first place.